# Setting some requirement for bounty points

Tags: discussion, bounty

I've made a [rather controversy question about lore in TES series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/104411/41413). So if anyone doesn't give a complete answer that I want, I'm thinking of putting a bounty on this question.

The question is: **Can I state in my question, in order to get the bounty the answer must be XXXX[insert requirements] ?** For example for my TES lore question, can I write like this? →

> To get the bounty, you must list <strike>all</strike> the possible afterlife destinations in TES world.

Thanks in advance. Cheers

Comment: aaaaand here comes the down-votes. I really cannot understand why....

Comment: It might be because it sounds like you're looking for a list-type answer; personally, I haven't downvoted this, but it could seem like using the bounty system to circumvent the rules.  Depends on how big the list might be.

Comment: Especially since bountied questions can't be closed.

Comment: Or maybe because your example text invites "[mu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_%28negative%29)" as an answer because it presumes that such a complete answer based on the lore is possible in the first place. (Spoiler from a TES lore fan: it isn't answerable like that, and I *upvoted* that question!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set make a bounty, you're allowed to pick one of several bounty reasons.

[image]

You're also granted a free form box to write things out in greater detail.

[image]

So, yes: you can set "whatever" requirements you'd like on your bounty (within reason). Just be aware that, once you do start the bounty:

- You can only award it in the next 7 days
- You cannot cancel your bounty, so if you didn't get the answer you were hoping for — tough.
- The bounty will be *automatically awarded* if you don't award it yourself

  - The answer must have been given after the bounty was started
  - The answer must have a score of at least +2
  - The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter
  - The answer will only receive half the bounty
- Your next bounty on the next question will have to be for more reputation than this bounty (or 500 reputation)

See also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067).

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I don't see why not. That's what the bounty text is for, really.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.  From the [bounty FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
>   the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at
>   least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no
>   answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

If an upvoted answer exists, it will get half the bounty, whether you want it to or not.

Though, I guess, technically you can make your requirement a requirement for the full bounty, as Oak pointed out.

Comment: Yes I know about that. But the real question here is can I set the requirement or not

Comment: Awarding the full bounty is entirely at your discretion, just like marking an answer as accepted.